# Time-optimal control - Coupled system of equations, control to the origin

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

> I want to find the time-optimal control to the origin $\underline 0$ for the following:

$\dot{x}_1=-3x_1 + x_2$ and $\dot{x}_2 = x_1 - 3x_2 + u$, $|u|\leq 1$

How do I go about doing this. I simply want an order of required tasks.

I think it is something like:

1) Convert to matrix form

2) Find eigenvalues of system

3) Construct Hamiltonian

4) Solve for variables

But I am unsure. Thank you!

---

Attempt(editting as I go):

$\begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -3 & 1\\ 1 &-3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} + u\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$(-3-\lambda)^2 =1$, $\lambda = -2,-4$, since this is real and of the same sign, it is a stable improper node.

Hamiltonian:
$H = \psi_0f_0 + \psi_1f_1+\psi_2f_2= \psi_1(-3x_1+x_2) + \psi_2(x_1-3x_2+u)$

Look at $u^* = \pm 1$

$u^*=1$
$$-3x_1+x_2=0,$$
$$x_1-3x_2+1=0$$
$$x_1=\frac18,x_2=\frac38$$

$u^*=-1$
$$-3x_1+x_2=0$$
$$x_1-3x_2-1=0$$
$$x_1=-\frac18,x_2=-\frac38$$

Comment: Just start and post back if you are hitting an obstacle.

Comment: @daw First obstacle: What is $\psi_0$ and/or $f_0$ here? Thank you

Comment: set $\psi_0=0$, $f_0=1$ to satisfy $T=\int_0^T f_0$

Comment: Thank you for the update @Daw. Where does $\int_0^T f_0 dt$ come from, I haven't seen that before. Also why did the workbook assume $u^*=\pm 1$, Is that because maximal or minimal controlling would be optimal?

Comment: If you can't identify $f_0$ in your textbook, how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: @daw It is a workbook written by a foreign professor who seems to teach physics primarily and uses strange notations, that aren't consistent with wiki. I am trying my best, but all I have are three worked examples that aren't particularly similar, and skip many steps. In fact trajectory solutions of ODEs wasn't even covered in this course.

Comment: @daw Can you recommend me a text?

Comment: @daw Shouldn't $\psi_0=A$ which is some constant?

Comment: Hmmm, I think you should not use a coupled system.